# using Jquery to automatically submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a form by using jquery automatically after page load

```
$(function(){

$("input[name=name]").val("somename");
$("input[name=email]").val("323@ds.com");
$('#aweberform').submit();

});
```

Both the name/email value can be seen to get populated on the form. But the submit event wont triggered.

Any one here that can shed any lights ?

thanks !

Comment: Syntax looks correct. Did you try to debug with Firebug?

Comment: Are you sure your form's `id="aweberform"` ?

Comment: Yeap. I purposely hacked the form to carry the id of aweberform

Comment: Here's the thing, firebug console is totally blank. the name/email field got populated though.

its kind of bizarre.

Comment: I tried using the firebug console and run interavtively by entering this

     $('#aweberform').submit();

well it returns the following and do nothing then

     [form#aweberform addlead.pl]

Comment: Have you got action and method set in the form ??

Comment: Neither is strictly necessary. The action will default to the same URL and the method will default to GET.

Comment: Try reducing the code to its bare essentials (just the form with two inputs, the relevant JavaScript/JQuery code, reference to the jQuery library, and doctype/html/head/body tags). If it still doesn't work, post the entire stripped-down document here.

Comment: Patrick is right should not need to be set - post your html for more help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ok i found out the problem

apparently the submit input cannot have the name submit

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="click to submit!">
```

changed to

```
<input type="submit" name="someothername" value="click to submit!">
```

and that got the problem fixed

Comment: same problem here   , i changed name , submit to other , but when i changed other then page hang , not submitted ,         and  when name="submit" then did not happen anything

Comment: alert is working but form not submit                                                        if(endTime <= time )
 {
  //alert('123');
  $("form").submit();
 }

Answer (score 5):

Try this `$('#aweberform').submit();`

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove my Submit button to get **`$('#myForm').submit()`** to work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Add a function in the submit.  Seems to work for me.

```
$('#aweberform').submit(function(){return true;});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `document.getElementById('formId').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it works:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.forms['form_id'].submit();
};
```