# Auto Submit Php Form with JAvascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I know this question have already answered but it didn't worked for me . I am creating a mcq question page . In which question have been generating by Json file. I am setting time limit of 90 minutes to the solving the question after 90 minutes the form must auto submit form to the the action="page" of the the form . I tried using set time out but it failed and i am also not getting any error.

This is  Form in HTM AND PHP

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
     echo   <form id="gi" method="post" name="mockForm" action="checkAnswer.php">

      <?php
      foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) {
          echo
          "<p><span class='que'> Question</span>&nbsp;&nbsp". $value['number']."&nbsp;&nbsp". "<br><hr class='line'>". $value['question']."<br><br>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio'  name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1' required>" ." " , $value['op1']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op2' required>" ." " , $value['op2']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op3' required>"." "  , $value['op3']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op4' required>"." " , $value['op4']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='0' required>"."LEAVE QUESTION"."</pre>".

              "</p>";
      }
      ?>
      <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
      <button onclick="hit(); handleClick();">click</button>
       </form>
```

This is Js

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#gi').submit();
    },10000);
</script>
```

checkANswer.php

```
<?php
$contentOfJsonFile = file_get_contents("example_10.json");
$JsonData = json_decode($contentOfJsonFile, true);

$correctAnswerArray = [];

$wrongCount = 0;
$correctCount = 0;
foreach ($JsonData as $key => $value) {
    array_push($correctAnswerArray, $value['correct_answer']);
}

    $userAnswerArray = $_POST;

$breakForeach = count($userAnswerArray) - 1;
$loopRun = 0;
foreach ($userAnswerArray as $key => $answer) {


    $questionNumber = substr($key, -1);

    if ($correctAnswerArray[$questionNumber] === $answer) {
        # increment correct
        $correctCount++;
    } else if($correctAnswerArray[$questionNumber] === 0) {
        # increment wrong
        $wrongCount++;
    }
    else {
        $wrongCount++;
    }


$loopRun++;

    if($breakForeach == $loopRun ) break;
}
echo "<br>".$correctCount."<br>";
echo $wrongCount;

?>
```

Comment: Just remove name attribute <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

Comment: FYI, with that solution, the user can refresh the page and the timer will reset. Not a great solution.

Comment: well the timer will be reset yes, but also the form so is that really a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961326/using-jquery-to-automatically-submit-form

Comment: yes ... @epascarello . And in next page i have an isset function checking for isset($_POST['submit']). If i remove name this will blunder my next page

Comment: @Prabhjot Singh Kainth He does not produce event on clicking of button, so this must work even if button not present.

Comment: @Ritik Singh first of all: you saying that target page is named `page` but the actual action page is `checkAnswer.php` can you post your `checkAnswer.php` file to see the content

Comment: no i have written page just for example. i have updated the post

Comment: @RitikSingh but provided file by you does not give us any sense, there is no checking if the `post` was submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
 document.forms['mockForm'].submit();
 }, 10000 );
```

Comment: Got this error TypeError: document.forms.mockForm.submit is not a function

Comment: change submit button name to btnsubmit because if button named submit it will override to submit function

Comment: In form or in JS ?

Comment: <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="SUBMIT">